# Handling rotation for UIPageControl

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a `UIPageControl` that contains a number of `UILabel` and `UIImageView` for every single page.

With the following code:

```
pageControl.numberOfPages=[arrData count];
for(int i=0;i<[arrData count];i++) {
    NSString *body=[NSString stringWithString:[[arrData objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"body"]];
    NSLog(@"body %d=%@",i,body);

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size.width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
}
```

I correctly see items in the portrait. When the device is rotated, obviously, the layout is broken because `self.scrollView.frame` is referred to as a portrait layout. How do I have to handle rotation creating `UIScrollViews` and `UIPageControls` by code?

Answer (score 2):

Your specific issues have nothing to do with the frame of your view being "landscape only" (which is an incorrect representation of frame and bounds, I do recommend you watch the beginning of the [talk on UIKit rendering](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.8270634034.08270634040.8367260927?i=1122536585), as they have a very good explanation of the coordinate system.  It has to do with the fact that your view is not being told what to do in the case of a rotation.

Auto-rotation, pre-constraints (iOS 6 >), can be handled with autoresizingmasks (specifically, in your case, I'm guessing [UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin) is probably what you need).  If you're targeting iOS 6+, it can also be constrained in place using [VFL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html).